# Ajax result in alert()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How can I get imageX show it's value when used outside of $.ajax()?

```
var imageX;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'php/my1.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: 'false',
    success: function(response){
        imageX = response[0].studentName,
        groupX = response[0].subjectId;
    }
});
alert(imageX);
```

Comment: Using `async: false` is not a good design as the site will stop responding (freeze) until the call has returned *(they are occasions this may be a good idea but I don't personally know of them)*. This means if there is an issue on the server and the call times out of even worse the server never returns at all your users will look at a web page which is unresponsive for a long time. You can use triggers, methods or `.then .when` instead to ensure you process `imageX` when the call is done as required but also not freeze the client.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

`async: 'false',`

to

`async: false,`

'false' is string which is cast to true by Jquery(JS).

Jquery Ajax Documentation says async accept boolean value.

> async (default: true):  Type: Boolean By
>   default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to
>   true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to
>   false.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

async:false 
will cause the jQuery.ajax() call to block until it returns. 
instead of this:

```
function your ajax_calling_function
    call your ajax 
    callback with results
```

Comment: It might be very helpful to the OP to explain *why*.

Comment: sure let me edit answer

Comment: Or why this approach is a bad idea to begin with.

Comment: Thanks Ravi... well explained...

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `async: false` ([type Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)).

If you wrap the `false` keyword with ', Javascript consider this is a `string`. And jQuery consider the `async` property setted as `true`

Answer (score 0):

Actually set `async: false` is a bad approach, quote from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/3085310):

> It is generally a bad idea to make AJAX calls synchronous. DON'T DO
>   IT. I'm serious. I only mention it here for the sake of completeness.
>   Why is it bad do you ask?
>
> JavaScript runs in the UI thread of the browser and any long running
>   process will lock the UI, making it unresponsive. Additionally, there
>   is an upper limit on the execution time for JavaScript and the browser
>   will ask the user whether to continue the execution or not. All of
>   this is really bad user experience. The user won't be able to tell
>   whether everything is working fine or not. Furthermore the effect will
>   be worse for users with a slow connection.

One way is to rewrite your code to:

```
function getImage() {
    var imageX;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'php/my1.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            imageX = response[0].studentName,
            groupX = response[0].subjectId;
        }
     });
     return imageX;
}
```

then you can pass it to a variable:

```
var result = getImage();
```

and get the data that is returned by the AJAX call like this:

```
result.success(function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```